# Should I use react-loadable or loadable-components for code splitting?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-loadable

I want to split my react code with server side rendering. To do that I have two options.

- loadable-components
- react-loadable

## loadable-components

React documentation suggested to use *loadable-components* for server rendered apps. But it has very few NPM weekly downloads.

## react-loadable

NPM weekly downloads of this package is very high compared to the previous one but according to *loadable-components* documentation this package is not maintained any more.

> react-loadable was the recommended way for React code splitting for a long time. However, today it is not maintained any more and it is not compatible with Webpack v4+ and Babel v7+. [Documentation Link](https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/loadable-components/docs/loadable-vs-react-lazy/#note-about-react-loadable)

Please guild me with proper package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though documentation of *react-loadable* says that *react-loadable* is not  compatible with Webpack v4+ and Babel v7+, I used  *react-loadable* and it worked. I did not face any issue in both server and client side rendering applications.

Comment: I always get a warning when using react-loadable. how did you do about that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy).
This will automatically load the bundle containing the OtherComponent when this component gets rendered.

React.lazy takes a function that must call a dynamic import(). This must return a Promise which resolves to a module with a default export containing a React component.

```
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <OtherComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: react lazy doesn't support server side rendering. [LINK](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)

Comment: try using `import()`, for more detail see this [post](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/server-rendering-code-splitting-and-lazy-loading-with-react-router-v4-bfe596a6af70)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW `loadable-components` is recommended by the [React team](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)

Also, `React.lazy` does not currently support SSR (as of May 2020)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me why I chose it in the first place :D